# webView ignoring CSS when loading epub3 content

Tags: android, css, webview, paging, epub3

I'm working on a reader, and we used to work on epub2, and I working on pagination effect using CSS file. I have recently received an ePub 3 file and it does not abide by the CSS rules that I have provided, although it works correctly when tried on Play Books android app.

Note that I have manipulated several features related to web view such as:

```
testWV.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
testWV.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

and this is the paging CSS used which as mentioned before works perfectly on epub2 files

```
html {
     height:heightplaceholderpx;  //set dynamically depending on phone screen size 

     width:100%;
   }

body {
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
     width:100%;

     pointer-events: none;
  }


#viewer {
     width:widthplaceholderpx;
     height:heightplaceholderpx; 
 }

#book {
    width:widthplaceholderpx;
    height:heightplaceholderpx;

    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-top:10px;

    -webkit-column-count:auto;
    -webkit-column-width:widthplaceholderpx;
    -webkit-column-gap:100px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.h {
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left:100px; 
    margin-right:100px;
 }


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
 }
```

This is how I'm integrating the CSS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="columnPaging.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    headplaceholder  //the header extracted from the xhtml file of the book
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viewer">
    <div id="book">
        bodyplaceholder   //the body extracted from the xhtml file of the book
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you can see you use this var `widthplaceholderpx` in his css. Normally it should be override it in the Java code. But when the `bodyplaceholder` was add to the body in the HTML I needed to override the `widthplaceholderpx` again. So the css would know what the actual height was.